# Chromebox running application display device MAC or serial no. in kisok mode

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebox

I want to have a quick way to see the MAC or serial no. while running the kisok App instead of checking in the console.
If can be shown the MAC or serial no. at the corner of the screen while running the kisok App it would be great for us if possible.
Thanks.
Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed the kiosk application you could potentially call : [chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/enterprise_deviceAttributes/#method-getDeviceSerialNumber) to get the serial number. The app and/or extension would need to be force installed on the device to access this information.